# Filtering out nested data frames by number of observations

Tags: r, dataframe, nested, dplyr, tidyverse

Following from: [Use filter() (and other dplyr functions) inside nested data frames with map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166360/use-filter-and-other-dplyr-functions-inside-nested-data-frames-with-map)

I want to nest on multiple columns, and then filter out rows by the number of items that were nested into that row. For example,

```
df <- tibble(
  a = sample(x = c(rep(c('x','y'),4), 'w', 'z')),
  b = sample(c(1:10)),
  c = sample(c(91:100))
)
```

I want to nest on column a, as in:

```
df_nest <- df %>% 
nest(-a)
```

Then, I want to filter out the rows that only have 1 observation in the data column (where a = w or a = z, in this case.) How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map/map_int` on the `data` column to return the `nrow` in each nested tibble, and construct the filter condition based on it:

```
df %>% 
    nest(-a) %>% 
    filter(map_int(data, nrow) == 1)
#   filter(map(data, nrow) == 1)        works as well

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      a             data
#  <chr>           <list>
#1     w <tibble [1 x 2]>
#2     z <tibble [1 x 2]>
```